# Mapping ORACLE function to Entity

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have invested whole day to understand how we can map ORACLE Function to JPA's entity. Later, I figured out it works similar as table.

My entity looks something like this,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DUAL", schema = "pfunc")
public class SystemSettings implements Serializable{


    private String setting1;
    private String setting2;
    private String setting3;
    ...
}
```

Now, in my entity `SystemSettings` I want all properties fields `setting1,setting2,setting3,..` to get value from ORACLE function `SYS_SETTINGS`.

In simple query I can do something like this , `select pfunc.SYS_SETTINGS(100) from DUAL` which sets value for property `setting1`, similarly I want to set multiple 
properties based on input given to `SYS_SETTINGS(?)` .

Can I achieve that in JPA Entity directly?

If yes , how? and if no, what are the alternative.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: **Keep it simple:** You don't need `(name=DUAL` because `dual` is a table in ORACLE. The simple way is to write a method that uses `PreparedStatement` with `select pfunc.SYS_SETTINGS(100) settings1, pfunc.SYS_SETTINGS(200) settings2, pfunc.SYS_SETTINGS(300) settings3 from DUAL` and read the *ResultSet* in a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your `Column` name of entity fields matches the alias of fields selected in query or function, it will be mapped automatically and you can use you entity as results without type casting.

simply something like this:

```
@Column(name="STR_1")
String str1;
@Column(name="STR_2")
String str2;

List<YourEntity> results = getSession().createSqlQuery("select foo as Str_1 , bar as Str_2 from your_table").list();
```